# How to animate a border?

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, frontend, loading

I want to create a circling border, as seen in the second state of this object. So the loading icon. How would I do that with JavaScript?

I'm not looking for someone writing out the full code, but would like some direction to what selectors etc to research.

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*JNE8gIhMViaL-Yri9SiCjg.gif]

Comment: so, what did you tried so far?

Comment: So far I don't even know where to start.

Comment: there is a js library called d3... it is really good for stuff like this https://codepen.io/ronnidc/pen/qmyzwv

Comment: Thanks! I don't try to use libraries though, I want to create it myself. I've almost managed to do it :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/dario-sanchez-martinez/pen/aRNxOb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is quite easy. Basically you start with a circle with a certain width and height,  a full border-radius and a transition to it. Then on hover for example, you increase the width of that circle. Doing this will smootly transform that circle into a rectangle. If you dont manage to make it work, i`l create some examples for you.

Take a look at this(hover on the circle)

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin:0 auto;
  transition: .5s;
}

div:hover{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

From here on you can modifiy it to fit your needs.

Comment: How do you mean exactly? If I change it into rectangle, won't it just fill in?

Comment: Oh I don't mean that part, I've already figured that out.

I mean the progress bar in the circle.

https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

You can see them here as well! But I want to do it with JS only.

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe this will help you https://codepen.io/devilishalchemist/pen/oXjYKB?editors=0010 (not mine)

Comment: Haven't worked with Sass yet, but I do think I have a new idea.

I will rotate a block over the circle (while the circle has an overflow: hidden), while another smaller circle is on top of it. By this I can give the illusion of a progress bar. Though, it's just a half block rotating from his side.

Comment: Glad to hear :)